# get posts that doesn't contain a specific tag

Tags: tags, get-posts

I want to get all the posts that do not contain the tag 'index'. How can it be done?

I mean in the reverse of

```
get_posts(array('tag' => 'index'))
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the `tax_query` with the `'NOT IN'` operator (untested)

```
$myposts = get_posts( 
    [
        'tax_query' => [
            [ 
                'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
                'terms'    => [ 'index' ],
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'operator' => 'NOT IN',
            ]      
        ]
    ]
);
```

where the taxonomy slug for *tags* is `post_tag`.

Comment: Always +1 for using a proper `tax_query`, it is so much more flexible ;-)

Comment: yes the syntaxly correct tax_query is flexible ;-) thanks  for fixing the silly mistake  ;-) @PieterGoosen

Answer (score 0):

Per WordPress Codex you should use a custom query for any of post types interrogations. Presuming your taxonomy is 'post_tag' instead 'tag' use the following code:

> $args = array(
>                   'post_type' => 'post',
>   'tax_query' => array(
>   array(
>   'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
>   'field'   => 'slug',
>   'terms'    => array('index'),
>   'operator' => 'NOT IN'         )));
>
> $custom_query = new WP_Query( $args );
>   while($custom_query->have_posts()) { $custom_query->the_post(); //your
>   custom code
>   }